# Is there any profiling api available for applications hosted with clr version as no managed code in IIS

Tags: .net-core, clr, clr-profiling-api

I'm using clr profiling api to track all the loaded assemblies, classes in the applications running in IIS. It works perfectly fine when my appication pool's .net clr version is set to v2.0 or v 4.0.

But the clr profiling api is not working when clr version is set to "no managed code".

I'm not sure what I'm missing. If the clr profiling api won't support "no managed code" applications then is there any alternative available to profile those unmanaged code applications.

Comment: No managed code means no CLR is loaded (ASP.NET 2.x/4.x are in process). How can you do CLR profiling without CRL? That's a question for yourself. .NET Core applications requires different setup, so you cannot use the same approach. https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/14786

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to this profiling. I've followed the steps from the link https://github.com/Microsoft/clr-samples/tree/master/ProfilingAPI/ReJITEnterLeaveHooks.
I built the profiler dll and set the environment variables. It works perfectly fine for console applications. But It is not working for .net core applications hosted in IIS.
What should I do to make it work for that case?

Comment: Probably you attach to the wrong process, https://blog.lextudio.com/a-closer-look-at-asp-net-core-execution-model-b3c332f6ed1

Comment: Sry I was wrong. Actually it works.
I was not able to see the log files I created. So I though it is not working. But it was a permission issue. Tons of thaks to you.